# Data is not in the file created

Tags: java

I have been trying to get data in the file but somehow i am not able to get the data in file, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

File is created as per the requirement, but they are empty.I ahve been trying to fix it by trying various things but it doesnt seem to work.

```
public class Node {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // handling the argument and placing it in respective variables for
    // further use
    int fromNode = 0;
    int toNode = 0;
    String message = null;
    int timeAfter = 0;
    // Write a message to the respective node after particular time interval
    // to the respective node after
    // message example node 2 9 "message" 20 & i.e node x node y the message
    // and
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        fromNode = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        toNode = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        message = args[2];
        timeAfter = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
    }

    System.out.println("from Node :" + fromNode);
    System.out.println("to Node :" + toNode);
    System.out.println("message  :" + message);
    System.out.println("time after which :" + timeAfter);

    // ******************************************************************

    // opening and closing the file for required appending the content to
    // those files

    try {
        String data = message;

        File fileTo = new File(File.separator + "Users"
                 + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator
                + "Files" + File.separator + "to" + toNode + ".txt");
        File fileFrom = new File(File.separator + "Users" 
                 + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator
                + "Files" + File.separator + "from" + fromNode + ".txt");

        // if file does not exists, then create it
        if (!fileTo.exists()) {
            fileTo.createNewFile();
        }

        if (!fileFrom.exists()) {
            fileFrom.createNewFile();
        }

        // true = append file
        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(fileTo.getName(), true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        bufferWritter.write(data);
        bufferWritter.flush();
        bufferWritter.close();

        FileWriter fileWritterfrom = new FileWriter(fileFrom.getName(),
                true);
        // System.out.println("------>"+data);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritterfrom = new BufferedWriter(
                fileWritterfrom);
        bufferWritterfrom.write(data);
        bufferWritterfrom.flush();
        bufferWritterfrom.close();
        System.out.println("Files have been created");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // ******************************************************************
```

Comment: You don't need all this `exists()/createNewFile()` stuff. It only repeats what the operating system already has to do when you create the file, so you're just making things worse. And `flush()` is redundant before `close().`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, the files were written, but not at the place you expected. The call `fileTo.getName()` just gives you the last component of the path. So you wrote to a file with name `to<some number>.txt` in the current directory.

Try to use just

```
FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(fileTo, true);
```

This should write to the file at the full path.

Btw. it is not necessary to create the files first.